# Android - Deeplink not working with custom url scheme

Tags: android, url-scheme, android-deep-link

I'm dealing with two problems here. This is my manifest:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

<data android:host="www.example.com" android:pathPrefix="/test/" android:scheme="https" />
<data android:scheme="myapp" />
```

- First of , I't redirect to my application when I type inside Chrome's
  URL. If I click on a link "https:[www.example.com/test/kakaka"](http://www.example.com/test/kakaka%22) inside
  an SMS, it shows if I want to open my application as expected. But,
  if I paste this link inside Chrome URL place and go, it does nothing.
- Second problem: Okay, so I decided to test with my custom scheme. I
  put on Chrome's URL "myapp://open" and it should work, right? But it
  doesn't. So, I removed the line <data
  android:host="www.example.com"..... and myapp:// WORKS! So, cant I
  have more than 1 scheme in one activity?

Answer (score 4):

When you put two `<data>` elements inside an `<intent-filter>` they are merged together. If you want two different specific urls, then create a second `<intent-filter>` with the second url scheme.